# VS Code Cloud Provision MX Chip can not find azure-board-cli module

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, node-modules, azure-cli

Cloud provisioning my MX Chip.

At this [step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-arduino-iot-devkit-az3166-get-started#provision-azure-services) I run `task cloud-provision` and get the following error when I run task cloud-provision.

```
> Executing task: node "/Users/$USER/azure-board-cli/out/cli.js" provision .bin <
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/gregorydegruy/azure-board-cli/out/cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Is this **azure-board-cli** some node package, part of the az cli download package, something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by doing a `brew uninstall --force node --ignore-dependencies` Then used the macOS steps once more in the download package from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-arduino-iot-devkit-az3166-get-started#prepare-the-development-environment